# phrase: after the restaurant

Tags: phrases

I have made up the sentences below.

(1) This morning, I did some shopping at ABC Mall and had breakfast. **After the restaurant**, I walked to DEF Park to meet my friend.

Is "after the restaurant" correct? Thanks.

Comment: **After leaving** the fast food restaurant...

Comment: It would be clearly understood, but it isn't idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be understood, but a couple of things strike me as slightly odd.  You don't mention "restaurant", so I have to infer that you went to a restaurant for breakfast.  If you'd said "... and ate breakfast at XYZ restaurant.  After the restaurant...." I would be happier.

<sub>The second thing is probably cultural.  It seems odd to go shopping and then eat breakfast. Breakfast is (for me) the first thing I do, (often before getting dressed!) I don't do anything without my mug of coffee and bowl of muesli. If I do eat out for breakfast, I wouldn't go to a restaurant. I'd go to a cafe or McDonalds (etc).  Perhaps this is just me.</sub>